Are smooth boundary manifolds boundaries of smooth manifolds?
If a smooth manifold bounds, does it smoothly bound? That is, if $M = \partial W$ is a smooth manifold that's null-cobordant in the category of, say, oriented compact topological manifolds, can $W$ be taken to be smooth?

I don't know the answer to this question, but you might find some success in searching the literature with a reframing of your question. Let $\Omega^O$ denote smooth bordism and $\Omega^{Top}$ denote topological bordism. You are asking the following question: If $M$ is in the kernel of the forgetful map $\Omega^O \to \Omega^{Top}$, is $M$ zero in $\Omega^O$? In other words, is this forgetful map injective? By Pontrjagin-Thom there's probably something to do with the map $BO \to BTOP$ in the answer to this question. I've been busy lately but maybe I can find some time to do some digging.

@kamills: Great, thank you. Unfortunately, I'm personally only familiar with some basic, classic results for the smooth case (using Pontryagin-Thom to show that $\Omega_^{O}$ is a free polynomial ring with certain genenerators) and not much at all for $\Omega^{Top}_$.

Yes.
Let $\Omega_*^{O}$ denote smooth bordism and $\Omega_*^{Top}$ denote topological bordism. This question is equivalent to asking if the forgetful map $\Omega_*^{O} \to \Omega_*^{Top}$ is injective, since if a smooth manifold $M$ is the boundary of some topological manifold $W$, then necessarily $[M] = 0$ in $\Omega_*^{Top}$, and if it's to bound a smooth manifold then $[M]$ must be trivial in $\Omega_*^{O}$.
Stong's "Notes on Cobordism Theory" Example 24 (on pg55) provide references and a short discussion that say that $\Omega_*^{O}$ is a direct summand of $\Omega_*^{Top}$ (Edit: This actually isn't necessary, the argument can be shortened to simply the last paragraph + the sentence before the last paragraph. Thanks to @DerivedCats for pointing this out in the comments!). Let the complement be $A$ so that $\Omega_*^{Top} \cong \Omega_*^{O} \oplus A$.
By properties of the Hom functor, the forgetful map is hence equivalent to a pair of maps $\Omega_*^{O} \to \Omega_*^{O}$ and $\Omega_*^{O} \to A$. If $[M]$ maps to zero under the forgetful map then it maps to zero in $\Omega_*^{O}$ (and in $A$). But if it maps to zero in $\Omega_*^{O}$, then its image has all $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ characteristic numbers (the Stiefel-Whitney numbers) trivial. Then the same must be true for its image under the forgetful map, which means that $M$ when considered as a topological manifold has all trivial Stiefel-Whitney numbers.
Stiefel-Whitney numbers don't depend on smooth structure, so this means that $M$ as a smooth manifold also has all trivial Stiefel-Whitney numbers. Thus $[M]=0$ in $\Omega_*^{O}$, and the forgetful map $\Omega_*^{O} \to \Omega_*^{Top}$ is indeed injective.

The fact that the forgetful map splits seems irrelevant to the argument. Couldn't you just say directly that if $M$ is trivial in $\Omega_^{Top}$ then its Stiefel-Whitney numbers are 0, hence $M$ is also trivial in $\Omega_^{O}$?

Ah, I see: $\Omega^O$ splits in $\Omega_*^{Top}$, and the fact that the Stiefel-Whitney numbers' vanishing is necessary and sufficient in the smooth case and necessary in the continuous case is enough for the result. Thanks for the reference to Stong (which I appreciate even outside this particular question).

@DerivedCats: Oh. Yeah, definitely. I got a little carried away with looking through Stong and some other references, and didn't consider the simpler argument--the splitting isn't relevant here.
